# Does google do anything to stop an app developer from just posting lots of 5 star reviews for themselves?

Tags: google-play-store

Anyone can set up a gmail account and anyone logged into gmail account with their android phone or tablet can leave google play app ratings (with android 4.2 I can even have multiple google accounts for the same tablet)

So is there anything preventing someone from just creating lots of gmail accounts, then logging into their android device, leaving a 5 star rating for their app?

Comment: See http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1665en/my_app_is_getting_1star_ratings_from_another_dev/

Comment: As a developer I regularly get 3 or 4 spam emails a week from companies offering to sell me 5 start reviews.

Comment: @Ifor : really? how did the spammers get your email?

Comment: @Diskdrive Most app authors put a support email address on their store page: it's encouraged by Google (and good business practice in general).

Comment: You have to provide an email contact to publish on Google Play there is an email developer link on every app page.  I do get more genuine support email request to it than people spamming me but not by much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

There is nothing that prevent developer from making lots of additional Google Accounts to provide 5 star ratings. Google recently made a change that require a Google+ enabled account to post reviews/star ratings on Google Play (at least using the on-device Play-app on certain phones) which is a small improvement from the past where a simple Gmail account would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post a review unless yo have downloaded the app.
So, in my opinion, it would be very tiresome to make so much accounts and then login with each account and then download the apps, especially in the case of paid apps.